# How to move the adbkey file path from C partition?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I moved the **.android** folder from C to another partition and created a new environment variable named **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** and the value **E:Android**. The problem now is that .android folder keeps getting recreated with 2 **adbkey** files inside old path in C.
It needs to get recreated in C otherwise the Emulator doesn't install apps.